# Author page from blog post

Tags: author-template

I am looking to build a custom WordPress blog which is simple enough but I have a requirement I need to meet.

On each blog post on the index.php page I want to display the authors name and image. The authors name will link off to the authors own page which details there bio and all there posts.

I also need to show the authors bio at the bottom of every single.php post he posts. I am unsure of how to go about this if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What have you coded so far? Please post your work and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post the relevant code from **index.php** and **single.php**.  [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) from each should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact contextual answer because you have not provided your code, however the functions (with example usage) listed below should do what you require.

**On each blog post on the index.php page I want to display the authors name and image.**

Inside The Loop you can get the name of the author by using [`the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta), you can get the image by using [`get_avatar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) and you can get the link to the authors page by using [`get_author_posts_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url) -

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>">
    <?php
    echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'));
    the_author_meta('display_name');
    ?>
</a>
```

**I also need to show the authors bio at the bottom of every single.php post he posts.**

Once again this is done inside The Loop.  You can also use [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) -

```
echo get_the_author_meta('description');
```